# Trouble with converting to Datetime object

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have the below data which is an object type variable named $timestamps

```
Sat Jan 15 16:21:24
Sat Jan 15 01:31:22
Fri Jan 14 20:58:09
Fri Jan 14 20:51:02
```

[image]

I'm having trouble converting it to Datetime object because of the weird date format. How would you handle this?

I would like it as a datetime object because I plan to convert from current (UTC) to EST.

TIA

Comment: `$timestamps` is an array. If you want to know the type of each element in the array, it must be referenced directly. `$timestamps[0].GetType()`

Comment: Note that without a year in your input, time zone conversions could be incorrect.  The dates that US Eastern Time shifts from EST to EDT and back vary from year to year.  You might assume the current year, but that won't work well at the start of the year looking back at the previous year's data, or at the end of the year looking ahead to the next year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the the `ParseExact()` method provided by the `[datetime]` class for this:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('Fri Jan 14 20:58:09','ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss',$null)

# returns a - datetime - object of:
# Friday, January 14, 2022 8:58:09 PM
```

- *dd* - for the day.
- *MM* - for the month.
- *HH* - for the hour - Capitalized for the 24 hour time format.
- *mm* - for the minutes.
- *ss* - for the seconds.

**Edit**: as suggested by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), we can use `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` to make the parsing specific to an *English* date time format. Also, changing *dd* to *d* as a more robust solution for days without 2 digits; which should cover both singular, and double digit days.

Seeing `$timestamps` is an **array** of *strings*, you can use a loop (*of your choice - in this case the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet*) to iterate through each string parsing the text to return a `datetime` object:

```
$timestamps | ForEach-Object {
    $culture = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
    $format  = 'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss'
    $date = [datetime]::ParseExact($_,$format,$culture,'AssumeUniversal, AdjustToUniversal')
    [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($date, 'Eastern Standard Time')
}
```

- Using `'AssumeUniversal, AdjustToUniversal'` ensures a UTC output.

Assuming from your comment that you'd like to do a conversion to Eastern Time, passing the newly created *datetime* object to `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId()` with an argument of the desired time zone, you can get your result in the new time zone.

---

*When using `$null`, the **CultureInfo** object that corresponds to the current culture is used.*

Comment: this is where I error out?
[datetime]::ParseExact($timestamps,'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss',$null)

When I place $timestamps as the first argument? Why?

Comment: @MattyS, is your `$timestamps` variable an **array** of *strings*?

Comment: When I do gettype it says object, array.  But acts like a string.  Sorry, Im new to this.

Comment: @MattyS, regrettably, PowerShell quietly converts an array to a string by space-concatenating its elements when calling .NET methods (which is virtually useless). Simply call the solution shown _for each element_.

Comment: @mklement0, if the `InvariantCulture` is "English", what culture would be used if `$null` is specified?

Comment: @MattyS: `$timestamps = "Sat Jan 15 16:21:24", "Sat Jan 15 01:31:22", "Fri Jan 14 20:58:09", "Fri Jan 14 20:51:02"; 
$timestamps.ForEach({ [datetime]::ParseExact($_, 'ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, 'AssumeUniversal, AdjustToUniversal') })`

Comment: @lit, `$null` is a placeholder for the _current_ culture (`$PSCulture` == `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture`). The [invariant culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) is _based_ on (US-)English, but is distinct from it (distinct from any real-world culture, including `[cultureinfo] 'en-US'`); notably, its format is guaranteed to never change.

Comment: You're welcome, @Abraham; thanks for updating. Looks good; the only thing I'd add: `AssumeUniversal` interprets the _input_ as UTC - by itself, that would be translated to a _local_ time; adding `AdjustToUniversal` outputs a UTC instance.

Comment: @mklement0, if `ParseExact()` is being used, does the culture make any difference?

Comment: @lit, yes, both with respect to _symbolic names_ (such as the names of months and weekdays) and with respect to _separator characters_ (unless you use _embedded quoting_ for chars. such as `/` and `:`, they are treated as _placeholders_ for the separators used in the target culture).

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.ParseExact()` method is probably what you're looking for.

```
PS C:\TEMP>$timestamp = 'Sat Jan 15 16:21:24'
PS C:\TEMP>$format    = 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss'
PS C:\TEMP>[datetime]::ParseExact($timestamp, $format, $null)

Saturday, January 15, 2022 04:21:24 PM


PS C:\TEMP>
```

Comment: Yes (with caveats), but your answer in essence duplicates an earlier one.